# How to create a specific table in LaTeX?

Tags: tables

I only know the basic concepts of creating a table in LaTeX. I want to know if it is easy to make a table like the one below and how:

[image: table]

Comment: That should be reasonably doable, yes. The tricky bit is likely to involve the bulleted list. Normally you'd create this with an `itemize` environment. But that may not work in a table. What I usually do is actually come out of the table environment, put the list in and then restart a new table. However, if you need something which 'looks just like this!' you may need a different solution. The best strategy would be for you to start making it, see how far you get and then post a specific question with your code if you get stuck.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format; in particular, it'd be great if you could show some of your efforts so far :)

Answer (score 3):

To give you a start:

## Method 1

I would not actually use this method unless I really had to. However, you may find you have to. So:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,british]{article}
\usepackage[scale=.85]{geometry}% probably you need a larger area than LaTeX defaults to
\usepackage{babel}% get hyphenation etc. right for UK English
\usepackage{array,longtable}% I assume your table may need to break across multiple pages
\usepackage{kantlipsum}% Just for filler text for the example


\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|>{\bfseries\sffamily}p{.2\textwidth}|>{\sffamily}p{.75\textwidth}|}
    \hline\endhead
    \hline\endfoot
    Something   &   Great things\\\hline
    Something Else  & One thing\newline Another thing\newline A third thing\\\hline
    A Somewhat Longer Something Else    &   More stuff\\\hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textbf{\textsf{Section N: Section Title}}}\\\hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|p{.95\textwidth}|}{%
      \kant[1]\medskip\par
      \textbf{Key Things}\medskip\par
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Thing 1
            \item Thing 2
            \item A non-Dr.\ Seuss Thing which is here just to make the place look untidy and dispel the myth that Seuss was a true Kantian. There is nothing to see here. Please restore your hat to normality.
            \item Thing 3
        \end{itemize}
      \kant[4]
      }\\\hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textbf{\textsf{Section N+1: Another Exciting Title}}}\\\hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|p{.95\textwidth}|}{%
      \kant[5]}\\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image: Table with vertical lines]

## Method 2

According to the documentation for `booktabs`, this is all wrong typographically. Having used that package for a while, I do find myself preferring its approach. That said, the non-booktabs defaults are spacing-wise actually somewhat worse than Word seems to manage so perhaps that's part of the issue. Anyway, here is a skeleton form of what I would *actually* be more likely to use (this stays inside the table but alters the presentation):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,british]{article}
\usepackage[scale=.85]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{array,longtable,booktabs}% add booktabs
\usepackage{kantlipsum}


\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{>{\bfseries\sffamily}p{.2\textwidth}>{\sffamily}p{.725\textwidth}}% note the loss of vertical rules throughout
    \toprule\endhead% \toprule, \bottomrule and \midrule replace \hline
    \bottomrule\endfoot
    Something   &   Great things\\\midrule
    Something Else  & One thing\newline Another thing\newline A third thing\\\midrule
    A Somewhat Longer Something Else    &   More stuff\\\midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{\textsf{Section N: Section Title}}}\\\midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{p{.95\textwidth}}{%
      \kant[1]\medskip\par
      \textbf{\sffamily Key Things}\par
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Thing 1
            \item Thing 2
            \item A non-Dr.\ Seuss Thing which is here just to make the place look untidy and dispel the myth that Seuss was a true Kantian. There is nothing to see here. Please restore your hat to normality.
            \item Thing 3
        \end{itemize}
      \kant[4]}\\\midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{\textsf{Section N+1: Another Exciting Title}}}\\\midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{p{.95\textwidth}}{%
      \kant[5]}\\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Whether your aesthetic sensibilities prefer the following is, of course, a matter for your judgement:

[image: Table with booktabs]